# Integrate Ranorex to Jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, ranorex

I'd like to Integrate `Ranorex` to `Jenkins` and i have 2 staff i'd like to check 
- First should only on the slave where  the `Ranorex` automation should be triggered that `Jenkins` is not started as a service or on both master and slave
- Second i'm working with `JenkinsFile` pipline and i'd like execute `Renorex` test from this script (`jenkinsfile`) but i couldn't found any solution any ideas

Thanks a lot  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with the first question you have:

The Jenkins service must be executed only on the machine where the automated tests are to be executed. You must also have Ranorex installed on that machine with a runtime license available. Jenkins can be configured to provide continuous integration, so each time you update the source code from Ranorex Jenkins will be able to automatically compile the solution and run the automated test.

Ranorex has an add-on that you can install in Jenkins to integrate the run configurations in order to be launched.